# How can I configure the rails console to show the line of code where a sql gets executed?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently when I run a method in the rails console it shows all the sql queries but I would like it to also show where in the code the sql is being called. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Running `ActiveRecord::Base.verbose_query_logs = true` in the console solved this issue for me. I found the info [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#verbose-query-logs)

Comment: Rails 7.0 update: the `ActiveRecord::Base` version of this method has been deprecated and you should now use `ActiveRecord.verbose_query_logs = true` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pry (http://pry.github.com/) might help. There is a `show-source` method that will do this when run from the console. Here is an example I did locally.

```
rails c

DEBUG: Chewy strategies stack: [2] <- urgent @ /Users/jmlockl2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ask/gems/chewy-0.9.0/lib/chewy/railtie.rb:49
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.22.5)
2.3.1 :001 > pry

[1] pry(main)> q=Question.last
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` ORDER BY `questions`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
=> ...

[2] pry(main)> q.email

  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 535441 LIMIT 1
=> "email@gmail.com"
[3] pry(main)> show-source q.email
[3] pry(main)> show-source q.email
From: /Users/...question.rb @ line 564:
Number of lines: 3
Owner: Question
Visibility: public

def email
  self.submitter.present? ? self.submitter.email : ''
end
[4] pry(main)>
```

Hope this helps!